# How to select rows based off a column entry using regex to filter?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Here is a schematic of the dataframe I'm working with (note, this is a *representative example*, and is not meant to demonstrate all possible entries in any column):

```
Name | Screen | Placeholder for other columns

Bill | GHRF (OOC) | text

Bob | GHRF (IC) | text

Sue | IRMS/CIR (OOC) | text

John | GHRF ISOFORMS IRMS CIR (OOC) | text
```

I am trying to select all the rows that have (OOC) in the `Screen` column.

Normally, I would filter a dataframe with something like this `dfnew = df[df['Column'] == 'Criteria']`, but that doesn't work with a regex.

I have also tried `dfnew = df[df['Screen'].filter(regex = r'OOC', axis = 0)]`, which I thought would work, but didn't.

Could someone please explain to me how I can select rows based on a column entry using regex?

What I would like to wind up with, is something like this:

```
Name | Screen | Placeholder

Bill | GHRF (OOC) | text

SUE | IRMS/CIR (OOC) | text

John | GHRF ISOFORMS IRMS CIR (OOC) | text
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DataFrame.filter` filters on the *column names*, not values. You're looking for `str.contains`.

```
dfnew = df[df['Screen'].str.contains(r'\(OOC\)')]
```

Or, if you don't need regex, switch it off—

```
dfnew = df[df['Screen'].str.contains(r'(OOC)', regex=False)]
```

```
print(dfnew)
   Name                        Screen
0  Bill                    GHRF (OOC)
2   Sue                IRMS/CIR (OOC)
3  John  GHRF ISOFORMS IRMS CIR (OOC)
```

If you're planning to do more indexing/assignment on `dfnew`, I'd recommend instead creating it with

```
dfnew = df[df['Screen'].str.contains(r'\(OOC\)')].copy()
```

To avoid a `SettingWithCopyWarning` later on.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!  Another responder suggested using `str.extract`.  The syntax if your suggestion is easier for me to follow, especially the regex part.  I don't suppose you could provide some insight into why `str.contains` might be preferable to `str.extract`?  Both approaches result in the desired outcome, I'm just trying to figure out why I might use one over the other.

Comment: @T.Kelly Actually, I do not recommend `extract` at all  if you're just checking for containment. `str.contains` returns a mask. "Yes" or "no". `extract` will first extract values via regex capture groups, and then perform an equality check on the result. A winding, two step approach with regex that isn't necessary. When using `str.contains` with this substring, you do not even need the regex switch... just turn it off with `regex=False`.

Comment: @coldspped awesome, thanks for clarifying what was going on 'behind the scenes'.  Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 2):

We can try `str.extract`

```
df[df.Screen.str.extract('\((.*?)\)',expand=True)[0]=='OOC']
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Another responder suggested using `str.contains`. The syntax if your suggestion is a little more difficult for me to follow, especially the regex part. I don't suppose you could provide some insight into why `str.extract` might be preferable to `str.contains`? Both approaches result in the desired outcome, I'm just trying to figure out why I might use one over the other.

Comment: @T.Kelly if you only want to filter the OOC row out m str.contains is better , if you need future using the data between bracket, `extract` is more comfortable to work with

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot for clarifying.  I appreciate your time!